# Possible to use Powershell to type a command into a third-party command line program?

Tags: powershell, command-line, sendkeys

I have an old, third party, command line, proprietary program which I'm calling from PowerShell.

Once started, this program accepts commands typed in followed by enter (like any other program), but it's very basic. It doesn't have flags, doesn't accept piped in arguments, etc. You have to start the program, type your command, hit enter and parse the results.

Is there a way I can use PowerShell to type in a command and get the resulting output? Right now the best solution I have is to call SendKeys.Send in a background job, but I'm not sure this will work.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this to see if it would work for you: http://wasp.codeplex.com/

legacy programs are hard to tell, however. this works with standard windows programs.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure it'll work, but it's probably my best bet.